# Problem with HeeksCAD

Tags: 11.10, software-recommendation, cad

I cannot make it work, I have no more ideas. Please, can anyone tell me if there is another 3D CAD similar to HeeksCAD?

Every `.deb` of HeeksCAD are broken, I downloaded the code, and it is missing some archives and/or the script to install it.

If anyone can help me I will appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Better late than never I hope. I suggest FreeCAD, available in the Ubuntu repositories. It offers a lot more features than HeeksCAD, and is a more active project.

v0.13 will be published soon (no date is set, should be in the coming weeks) with a ton more features, a stable PPA repo will be available to update FreeCAD.

Although if what you want is the CNC component in HeeksCAD, then you're out of luck, FreeCAD does not offers this functionality yet.

Disclosure: I'm contributing to the FreeCAD project. :-)